# Setting Control's Value in Another Control's onChange Handler in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a functional component (so no "this") which renders two Form Controls from React Bootstrap 1.0.1.  One is a File Control and the other is a text control.  In the onChange handler of the File Control, I'd like to set the value of the text control.

This shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this example:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function FileExample(props){

    const [filename, setFilename] = useState('');

    function changeHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setFilename(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
            <input type="text" value={filename}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I used something similar `<Form.Control required type="text" placeholder="Document Name" id="docName" value={filename} readOnly />` At first I did not have the "readOnly" attribute and React complained to me.  Thank you.  I guess I was not thinking of the basics!

Comment: @Rintoul, you are welcome bro and thank you so much for appreciating my answer :)